# How to get negated value from Lodash get() method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I am using `lodash get()` method to get the value at path of an object.

However my use case demands me to get negated values sometimes.
And I can't use the negate symbol or negate method() after retriving the value.
This is because the component where I am using the `get()` method is very generic.
And usually I need the direct `get()` values.

Is there any way, something like passing a negate sign to the object path as an argument to the get method?

For example - `lodash.get('!styling.fullWidth')`

I am using `Javascript` and `Vue.js`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try `return !get(this.item, setting.visibilityToggle);`

Comment: I can't apply that directly, because it's a very generic function. The best I can think is using regex to check for the negate sign and then conditionally return a negated value.

Comment: It's not conventional to use a string like that. Yes, you'll need to parse it some way. You could do this as a part of your implementation, writing `get` from scratch would take only several strings

Answer (score 0):

Using `regex` was the simple solution I found to get it working the way I wanted.

With a simple regex test, I was able to return the values conditionally.

```
/^!/.test()
```

Here is my solution -

```
showSetting(setting, type) {
  if (setting.type === type) {
    if (setting.visibilityToggle) {
      const hasNegateSymbol = /^!/.test(setting.visibilityToggle);
      if (hasNegateSymbol) {
        return !get(this.item, setting.visibilityToggle.slice(1));
      } else {
        return get(this.item, setting.visibilityToggle);
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
},
```